# How to update error value in ModelStateDictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project and want to be able to update Error messages on the fly inside `ModelStateWrapper`, but the problem is that there are no set methods for specific key, and dictionary is readonly.

```
var x = new ModelStateDictionary(this.ModelState);

foreach (var item in x.modelState)
{
    if (item.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var y in err.errors)
        {
            if (item.Key == y.Key)
            {
                //Some magic needed here to update error name with y.Key                                                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Just a thought, but you can always attempt to execute private setters and methods with Reflection, distasteful as it may be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add errors to the model state dictionary with:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("ErrorKey", "Error Message");
```

To change the error you could do:

```
ModelState.Remove("ErrorKey");
ModelState.AddModelError("ErrorKey", "New Error Message");
```